# ListPointPlot3D in a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I have a program using `Manipulate`. The program given certain values will compute some values. I want these values to appear in a 3D list plot but the problem I am facing is that when the user changes the parameter the previous plot will disappear.

How can I keep the previous points plotted even after the user changes the values of x or y with the Manipulators? I want the user to see all the points.

Here is an example:

```
Manipulate[ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {x + y, x, y/2}}], 
  {x,  0, 10}, 
  {y, 0, 5}]
```

I want the plot to show all the points where the user changes x and y not just the latest.

Comment: Belated welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply maintain a list of points to which you append the latest values:

```
data = {{0, 0, 0}};
Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[AppendTo[data, {x + y, x, y/2}]], 
 {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}, TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}]
```

[image]